# Generate valid random rgb color strings

Tags: java, random

I'd want to see if is possible to optimize performance even further of the following generate color method.

```
package generacolorrgb;

import java.util.Random;

public class GeneracolorRGB {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(generateColor(r));
        }

    }

    private static String generateColor(Random r) {
        StringBuilder color = new StringBuilder(Integer.toHexString(r
                .nextInt(16777215)));
        while (color.length() < 6) {
            color.append("0");
        }

        return color.append("#").reverse().toString();

    }

}
```

Average time it takes on my machine: 1650704.333 ns

Comment: If you want to test it with @Zymus code it takes 93.3 nanoseconds average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Faster implementation

If you build the string yourself using a character array, you can generate the string much faster.  The slowest part of your string conversion is probably the call to `Integer.toHexString()`.

I got 2x the speed using this code:

```
private static String generateColor(Random r) {
    final char [] hex = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                          '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    char [] s = new char[7];
    int     n = r.nextInt(0x1000000);

    s[0] = '#';
    for (int i=1;i<7;i++) {
        s[i] = hex[n & 0xf];
        n >>= 4;
    }
    return new String(s);
}
```

I ran 10000000 iterations to test the timing vs the original code.

Comment: An arguable more expressive version of creating the `char[] hex` array: `"0123456789abcdef".toCharArray()`. :)

Comment: @h.j.k. I'm not a java expert so I don't know what's best.  I tried to write something that would be constructed at compile time instead of at runtime.  Are our two versions equivalent?

Comment: Actually that's a good point. `"string".toCharArray()` simply makes a copy of the underlying `char[]` content of the `"string"` using `System.arraycopy()`. It should be quite close performance-wise, especially if we extract `hex` out as a `static final char[]` field, for example.

Comment: As @h.j.k pointed its practically equivallent. 30.7ns amazing!

Answer (score 5):

Here are some comments related to your code:

- *Strange place to initialise the `Random()`* – This should either be in within the `generateColor()` function, or some static initialisation. As it stands now, it looks strange that you need to include the random generator to as a parameter to your function. You are better of using a static initialization
- *Strange magic number, `16777215`* – What is this number? It is not very clear that this is actually the `0xFFFFFF` denoting the maximum color number. Also note that `nextInt(n)` returns a number in the range `0` up to `n`, but not including `n`. In other words, you should use `0x1000000`
- *Tricking into being 6 characters* – If you add `0x1000000` to the number before converting to hexadecimal you are ensured six digits, and don't need the trick for 6 characters, and can return a substring (instead of using a while loop)

Applying this and your code looks something like this:

```
package generacolorrgb;

import java.util.Random;

public class GeneracolorRGB {

    static Random randomGenerator;

    static {
        randomGenerator = new Random();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(generateColor());
        }
    }

    private static String generateColor() {
        int newColor = 0x1000000 + randomGenerator.nextInt(0x1000000);
        return "#" + Integer.toHexString(newColor).substring(1, 7);
    }
}
```

**Added:** An even nicer variant would be:

```
    private static String generateColor() {
        int newColor = randomGenerator.nextInt(0x1000000);
        return String.format("#%06X", newColor);
    }
```

Here we let the [Formatter](//docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) handle the formatting issue, and it does indeed look nicer! And we don't need to make sure the random number is above the legal range, as the formatter handles it.

Comment: "As it stands now, it looks strange that you need to include the random generator to as a parameter to your function"  Are you kidding me?  That's the best line of code in the original submission.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, Your mileage may vary, but to include a random generator as a function parameter is not good coding in my world. Why would you like to do so? It is part of the intrinsic of the function.

Comment: Please don't fight... I specified that the method had to be optimized, because I use this method on a seam project with the random generator initialized as a private field so it's beyond the central subject of the question.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro, Then you already do something similar to me initialising it elsewhere. That is still good! :-)

Comment: @holroy Your optimization Took 1370277 ns Awesome! and the one with the formatter 14158638.33 ns

Comment: @holroy because trying to write tests with deterministic outcomes becomes ridiculously complicated when methods start instantiating their own instances of RNG.  You can pass an RNG with a fixed seed to a method that accepts an RNG.  (You are, of course, correct that the RNG is an implementation detail of the generator -- the example would be better off with a constructor that accepts an RNG, and a clean method signature).

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, that is where mocking enter the playground, or having an constructor (or static initialization) to override it. Both options better than passing it as a function parameter, but you do have a valid point that testing needs a more deterministic approach.

Answer (score 3):

Performance-wise, this is pretty good, though there might be a micro-optimization that I'm not seeing. However, you do have a randomness issue. I ran a sample run of 500M iterations, and these are the color averages I saw:

```
redAverage=119.970404962
blueAverage=127.471355866
greenAverage=127.994226206
```

I would propose the following alternative. It performs at about the same speed over 500M iterations, may be slightly easier to understand, and distributes values evenly.

```
public final class GeneracolorRGB {

    private static final int ITERATIONS = 100;

    private static final String[] VALUES = {
            "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
    };

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            System.out.println(generateColor(random));
        }
    }

    private static String generateColor(final Random random) {
        final StringBuilder color = new StringBuilder("#");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            final String value = VALUES[random.nextInt(VALUES.length)];
            color.append(value);
        }
        return color.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea behing using number `16777215` was to avoid generate several random numbers and use just one. In such sense I think that

    StringBuilder color = new StringBuilder("#");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color.append(Integer.toHexString(r.nextInt(15)));
    }

will be faster, wich was the original code approach.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Have you tested? I have. The performance is indistinguishable.

Comment: Yours take 1581960.667 ns on my machine... as you said no big difference.

Comment: Great analysis with the randomness bias. The OP's code looks so unsuspicious that this pattern could be a good candidate for IOCCC-style competitions.